# Unloading a tab bar controller

Tags: ios5, tabs, controller

I am developing an ios5 application using the storyboard feature and am running into an issue. Hoping somebody can provide me with a quick solution.
Refer to the storyboard image given below:[image: storyboard image]

What I want to be able to accomplish is to go from Page 2 to the First Page. Now I know I can create a segue from Page 2 to the First Page and simply execute it; but that would mean that i have not unloaded the tab controller, but have simply loaded another view on top of the tab bar controller. 
I would think the correct way would be to unload the tab bar controller and then display the first page, so that the navigation controller is again in charge of the display. How can one accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this. In the logout method simply popToRootViewController.

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```